# How to move /usr to a new partition?

Tags: partitioning

My `/usr` folder needs to get moved to a new partition. How can I do this without erasing the contents?

Can this be done while Ubuntu is running, or do I need to use the LiveCD for this?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It would be safest to use a Live CD, but you could do:

- copy all the files to a new partition, making sure that the contents of `/usr` do not change while you are doing this.
- edit `/etc/fstab` so that `/usr` will be mounted on the next reboot
- reboot
- delete the old files

See below for details on each step.

Note that you can't mount the new partition on `/usr` while running as there will be lots of files in `/usr` that will be open.

#### Copying the files

I would use `cp -a`. `-a` is the archive option. From the [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/en/man1/cp.1.html):

```
-a, --archive
          same as -dR --preserve=all
...
-d     same as --no-dereference --preserve=links
...
-P, --no-dereference
          never follow symbolic links in SOURCE
...
--preserve[=ATTR_LIST]
          preserve      the      specified      attributes       (default:
          mode,ownership,timestamps),  if  possible additional attributes:
          context, links, xattr, all
...
-R, -r, --recursive
          copy directories recursively
```

#### Editing /etc/fstab

You need to know the UUID of your new partition. You can see the mapping by doing:

```
$ ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/
```

or

```
$ sudo blkid
```

And then add this line to `/etc/fstab`:

```
UUID=634c31a5-e27c-4e33-ac67-2e22491a30c2 /usr           ext4    defaults        0       2
```

Change the UUID to your UUID, and change `ext4` to be the file system type you are using - you should know this if you have set up the partition.

#### Delete the old files

After the reboot, the old files in `/usr` on the root partition will be hidden by the new partition mounted on `/usr`. But we can use some [mount bind trickery](https://askubuntu.com/questions/669/is-it-possible-to-delete-files-when-another-filesystem-is-mounted-on-the-path) to get to the old files and then delete them.

```
$ sudo mount --bind / /mnt
$ sudo rm -rf /mnt/usr/*
$ sudo umount /mnt
```

But some slight mistyping (say, hitting Enter when you'd only typed `sudo rm -rf /mnt` ) could cause disaster, so I would only use this method if you were very confident in what you were doing, really couldn't deal with any downtime, or had no physical access to the machine and hence were unable to boot off a live CD or live USB stick.

Comment: `rsync` is so much better suited for this than `cp`

Comment: Could I use this guide to do the opposite. I mean move the /usr folder to root partition?

Comment: @MarcoCeppi Could you expand on that? Maybe give a variant answer that uses `rsync` instead?

Comment: Replace cp command with `rsync -avz`. Rsync allows you to restart copies and should generally be used when moving between partitions, block devices, or machines.

Comment: Also I left off the `-f` when I did `sudo rm -r /mnt/usr` as an extra safeguard against **bad things**.

Comment: Do NOT use `cp`. It doesn't preserve HARD LINKS. This **will break** package upgrades in future. For example `/usr/bin/s2p` and `/usr/bin/psed` is the same file. Moving with `cp` will create 2 independent versions of that file. Do `rsync -aH` instead.

Comment: CAN SOMEONE POST A REAL EXAMPLE OF THIS? So many commands posted, but nobody isn't going into detail on how to do it, for example, how should a real case command look like? I've used rsync -avz, and it created "usr" folder on my new partition. Is that okay, or should contents of the folder be directly there, without the "usr" folder on the actual partition?

Comment: First of all, skip the -z flag - it enables compression, which given you're not sending the files over a network is useless overhead (except that rsync is usually smart enough to ignore it, but still, might as well drop it).  @AleksandarStefanović you definitely want the contents there, not the folder, and the reason it's happened that way is due to some rsync quirks: it treats `rsync -avH a/ b` differently from `rsync -avH a b`, copying the *contents* of folder `a` (that is, `a/*`) in the first case and the *folder itself* in the second.  Make sure you use the slash here.

Comment: I did exactly as you told above, but after I reboot I just can't get something right. My SD card are mounted on `/usr` thats all right. But I don't have wifi and powermanager and so on. I don't think it is because `/etc/fstab` since I exchange the `/ mounted` and `/usr mounted` there is still the problem. Even when I don't mount just a `ln -s`, it also won't work. All I can do is to preserve the former `/usr` and `mount sd to /usr` **manually** after startup and that is annoying. Can you solve this? Thanks

Comment: Is the '2' in the  line added to /etc/fstab the partition #?  I am wanting to move /home as well.  I am wondering if it is '3'

Comment: @RonPiggott if you read the [fstab man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/fstab.5.html) you'll learn that : `This field is used by fsck(8) to determine the order in which filesystem checks are done at boot time. The root filesystem should be specified with a fs_passno of 1.  Other filesystems should have a fs_passno of 2.` So stick with 2 for your home partition

Comment: I can't delete original /usr folder, I deleted everything in it but `rm -rf /mnt/usr` gives me `rm: cannot remove '/mnt/usr/': Device or resource busy`, even after reboot :/

Comment: Any advice on how to do this using a live CD / USB stick? It might be obvious, but not to me.

Comment: About the advice on not using `cp` - it appears that using `cp -a` *does* preserve hard links. I tend to use `cp -ax` just to be sure I'm limiting myself to the actual filesystem...

Comment: It's better to use find follow by cpio, such as `find . -depth -print0 | cpio --null -pvdm /usr_new/` because some partitions have block devices, binds, mounts, other kinda files. So with find you can manage what kinda files u will need to copy. Finally, do not forget to validate that previous to copy the files non of them are being used, this can be checked with `lsof /usr/`.

Answer (score 8):

Since most libraries that are used are in /usr, I would not recommend to move this directory while running Ubuntu. In fact, you probably get error messages when you try to do this. Hence, the best is to use the LiveCD.

You can use several possibilities to move/copy the files cp, rsync etc. you want to make sure that any symlinks are created and not just copied. cp and rsync both have options for this.

After moving the files to the other partition you need to add another mount in /etc/fstab to mount the new partition to /usr.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I've done it (following the [Hamish's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/668/830570) and the comments):

1. Copy all the files the newly created partition (replace with the location of your partition, it should look similar to mine):

   ```
    rsync -avz /usr/* /media/aleksandar/750b84e2-e65f-4309-ade5-5af0033a937c
   ```
2. Edit `/etc/fstab` (same as in [Hamish's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/668/830570), of course, replace `xxxxxx` with your UUID)

   ```
    UUID=xxxxxx/usr           ext4    defaults        0       2
   ```
3. Reboot the system
4. After rebooting, open System Monitor or similar application to see whether your new `/usr` partition is mounted, and to safety-check whether everything went as planned.
5. After checking that everything is alright, you can delete your old `/usr` partition. I will keep mine just in case something goes wrong.

Comment: @cmks because I felt like other answers were incomplete - I didn't get complete solution from one answer, and none of the answers didn't have enough detail to them. I felt like users who would come to this question would need help. It doesn't matter if it's five years old if someone still needs the information from this question.

Comment: Why is everybody rebooting their system? Shouldn't a `sudo mount -a` allow it to keep on running?

Comment: @Hagen I guess it's just for good measure

Comment: How can I to make step 7, if step 4 was skipped? `mount --bind` is the answer.

Comment: @vp_arth what he means is that he renamed it to `/usrBACKUP` while the system was still running, and then it crashed. So don't do that. Instead, just reboot the system normally. Don't worry about having two `/usr` folders, Linux will happily hide the old one and mount the new one in its place. (You can delete the hidden folder, but I'm not explaining that here.)

Comment: I end with moving `/usr/local` only. `/usr` binding is dangerous, because of `/usr/sbin/init` process location

Comment: It is needed to reboot vs. simply mounting in real time because there are files open in the usr directory. As per @Hamish said, If you do an fstab, then also mount without rebooting, the pointers to those files may be pointing to the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

I performed a migration of the `/usr` partition but I had some issues which I will be detailing in the following lines:

- issues on `/etc/fstab` at the moment to mount by **UUID** (specially when u restart the OS), getting the error **UUID specified does not exist**.

#### Installation

**Linux Distribution**: Ubuntu 18 (x86_64)

The steps I performed were the following (`/dev/vda` will be my new disk):

- Start the system in `Recovery Mode` or single user.
- Validate that non of the files of `/usr` are being used:

```sh
lsof /usr
```

- Create the new directory:

```sh
mkdir -p /usr_new
```

- Create a pvs, vgs and lvs partitions:

```sh
pvcreate /dev/vda
vgcreate data_vg /dev/vda
lvcreate -l 100%FREE -n usr data_vg
```

- Make a filesystem of the lv partition ( to identify the full path of the lv, execute `lvdisplay`) and mount the partition to the new directory `/usr_new`:

```sh
mkfs.ext4 /dev/data_vg/usr
mount -t ext4 /dev/data_vg/usr /usr_new
```

- Move the content of the `usr` partition to the new one:

```sh
cd /usr
find . -depth -print0 | cpio --null -pvdm /usr_new/
```

- Rename the old one and mount to the new one:

```sh
mv -v /usr /usr_old
umount /usr_new
mkdir /usr
mount -t ext4 /dev/data_vg/usr /usr
```

- Make permanent changes on `/etc/fstab` file ( add the following line to the end of the file):

```
/dev/mapper/data_vg-usr /usr    ext4    defaults    0   0
```

- Confirm that mounts are working as expected:

```sh
mount -a
```

- Reboot the system:

```sh
init 6
```

#### Troubleshooting

In case you face incidents during the boot for mount incidents, take into consideration the following steps to fix / debug the issue:

- From the grub options, type `e` and add the following text after the vmlinuz arguments:

[image]

- Press control + x, and boot from the edited option (the first one most probably)
- If you are addressed to the `initramfs` terminal, type the following:

```
initramfs > chroot /root
```

- You will be moved on to your root system partition, from there try to check the content of the `/etc/fstab` and made the required changes, or return the system like it was before.

```
$ exit
initramfs > reboot
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to move /usr folder from the root partition to a new one, because the disk was full. It was a sort of "temporary" system, so it was ok for me to use an available 16 gig stick, the only thing I could spare at the moment. I recall here the steps I followed, if they are of any help for anyone.

make a new GPT, new ext4 (g, n & w options) on the stick. For me it was on sdd, please be carefull, find which is yours

```
sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdd
```

make filesystem

```
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdd1
```

mount somewhere the stick

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/16G
sudo mount /dev/sdd1 /mnt/16G
```

copy everything to the stick (-a=keep permissions, -h=human readable) (instead of "cp -r /usr /mnt/16G" use rsync)

```
rsync -ah --progress /usr /mnt/16G
```

find the UUID of the stick

```
sudo blkid
```

put it in fstab

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
    UUID=40xxxx3f-exx8-4xx3-9xxx-xx055xx34xx5 /usr          ext4    defaults        0       2
```

poweroff

```
sudo poweroff
```

boot with a LiveUsb ubuntu and rename original /usr to something else, like /usr1

create a new empty folder on the root partition and name it "usr", for the stick to be mounted on, as stated in fstab. **Otherwise you will get a nice initramfs on next boot**
(sorry, I haven't tested Hamish Downer's advise for [$ sudo mount --bind / /mnt] [$ sudo rm -rf /mnt/usr/*] [$ sudo umount /mnt])

reboot to the normal installation

Hope I didn't forget or messed up anything!

Edit: You can now remove /mnt/16G and IF everything is nice 'n' smooth, delete the /usr1 to regain the space!