# Is it possible to delete files when another filesystem is mounted on the path?

Tags: filesystem, delete, mount

Having just written an answer about [moving /usr to a new partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/656/how-to-move-usr-to-a-new-partition/668#668) I was wondering about deleting files once a new partition has been mounted. To use the example from the question, is it possible to mount a new partition on `/usr` and then delete all the files under `/usr` on the root partition to free up space on the root partition.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Not *directly*, but there is a way around that: `mount --bind` is your friend:

```
# Existing directory with a couple files in it
root@nkubuntu1004:~/test# ls testdir
bar  foo

# Mount a filesystem over existing directory
root@nkubuntu1004:~/test# mount -o loop testfs testdir
root@nkubuntu1004:~/test# ls testdir
lost+found

# Bind mount root filesystem to another directory
root@nkubuntu1004:~/test# mount --bind / bindmnt

# Can now get to contents of original directory through the bind mount
root@nkubuntu1004:~/test# ls bindmnt/root/test/testdir/
bar  foo

# Remove a file
root@nkubuntu1004:~/test# rm bindmnt/root/test/testdir/bar
root@nkubuntu1004:~/test# ls bindmnt/root/test/testdir/
foo
root@nkubuntu1004:~/test# ls testdir
lost+found

# Unmount filesystem
root@nkubuntu1004:~/test# umount testdir

# Observe the change having taken effect
root@nkubuntu1004:~/test# ls testdir
foo
root@nkubuntu1004:~/test#
```

See also `man mount` -- search for "bind mounts".

Comment: Excellent answer - I'll just add a link to an [online version of the mount man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/en/man8/mount.8.html).