# Moving the /usr directory to a different partition

Tags: partitioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to move /usr to a new partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/656/how-to-move-usr-to-a-new-partition)

I am running 11.04 on my Cr-48 notebook from Google along side of Chrome OS. I have moved my home directory to a 64GB partition on my external drive.
I have another partition on this drive. I wish to know how to move the /usr directory to the empty partition. How can I do this.  Here are some additional details on the system.

Empty Partition

```
/dev/sdb2: LABEL="UBUNTUUSR" UUID="ba9d8f02-6f29-438e-a27c-20a5bafe2ec3" TYPE="ext4"
```

How do I do this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Since you already moved /home, I suppose you already know how to mount a partition. What is your problem with moving /usr?