# how to recover from mounting /usr/ nosuid

Tags: sudo, fstab, su

[I was able to move `/usr`to an external harddrive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61026/moving-the-usr-directory-to-a-different-partition). In fstab I mistakenly mounted the drive with `nosuid`. Now I can't use `sudo` or `su`. I can't edit the `fstab` entry. When I manage to open it I can't do so as root and it therefore is read-only. I can provide more details if need be.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You probably have a mistake in your question: `fstab` sits in `/etc/` so it does not reside on `/usr/`(??)

Comment: @Rinzwind Sorry that was referring to another question which I asked [earlier](http://askubuntu.com/questions/61026/moving-the-usr-directory-to-a-different-partition) I mentioned that because when I edited fstab to mount the usr directory I set it to mount as nosuid. This is, to my knowledge, what caused the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm probably late to the party, but recently I learned that having `/usr` on a separate partition is not such a good idea anyway - some things during the early Linux boot expect `/usr` to be available - so generally there will be silent failures unless you also modify the initrd to mount /usr during the early boot:

```
Most of the failures you will experience with /usr split off and not pre-mounted
in the initramfs are graceful failures: they won't become directly visible, 
however certain features become unavailable due to these failures.
...
Here's a short, very in-comprehensive list of software we are aware that currently
they are not able to provide the full set of functionality when /usr is split off 
and not pre-mounted at boot: udev-pci-db/udev-usb-db and all rules depending on
this (using the PCI/USB database in /usr/share), PulseAudio, NetworkManager, '
ModemManager, udisks, libatasmart, usb_modeswitch, gnome-color-manager, usbmuxd, 
ALSA, D-Bus, CUPS, Plymouth, the locale logic of most programs and a lot of 
other stuff.
```

See [Booting Without /usr is Broken](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/separate-usr-is-broken) for more details.

Comment: Well, Ubuntu of course doesn't use `systemd`, so the details of that page and the boot order don't exactly apply.  But generally, I agree, it's not a great idea.  Have a separate `/boot` if you want, and then the rest of the OS on `/`.

Comment: Good catch! Still, I agree with you agreeing with me that it feels extremely fragile :)

Comment: Waaait a minute!.. The problem is caused by udev, not by systemd: "systemd itself is actually completely fine with /usr on a separate file system that is not pre-mounted at boot time"; "(some) udev rules ... will silently fail to work if /usr is split off and not pre-mounted" :)

Answer (score 6):

Boot into recovery mode and choose the root shell option, then edit and fix your fstab:

```
nano /etc/fstab
```

Comment: This is the easiest method :)

Comment: Unfortunately I wasn't able to boot into recovery due to several reasons. Thankyou for your input.

Answer (score 2):

I am exactly not sure if I understood you right but I think you may could reboot your machine and go in grub in the recovery mode and create a new user or use your normal user and give him back his admin/sudo permissions but I may understood your wrong. Just a question at last: You have stil got a /usr folder right? If not uhh this will a little bit mor complicated.(I think)