# Change Ubuntu Software Center Download directory to Different drive from OS drive?

Tags: software-center, hard-drive, ssd

Ok, Im relatively new to Ubuntu and have a custom built computer. I am utilizing three drives, 1 ssd, and 2 hard drives. I have installed my OS to my ssd, and want to use the other two for gaming and various other reasons while mounted for this OS. I am having to redirect all important programs to download or install to the other hard drives, I am having issues with Ubuntu Software Center. Is it possible to change the download directory to my other drives?

Answer (score 0):

When you download a package via Software Center, it is installed to your /usr/bin folder. Otherwise you will not be able to start it.

*Edit: Your /usr/bin folder is, as I understand, on your SSD.*

Comment: thanks a bunch! that is a good thing to know. Though I don't know the commands to switch it from this drive to another. Though my friend pointed me to this source as a good way to start, but im at a loss as to where to start exactly: http://linux.chrissweeney.co.uk/topic.php?t=16

Comment: I see your problem. But if you don't exactly know how to set up partitions, mounting etc. it'd be better if you consider professional help with it. _E: I have no experience in moving system folders to other partitions._

Comment: Look here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/656/how-to-move-usr-to-a-new-partition