# Change location of /opt or /usr? Or other way to improve system portability and save SSD space

Tags: partitioning, upgrade, ssd

I have a 32 GB mSATA drive which I set to be the mountpoint of `/`.
Then I have a 500 GB drive which is set to be `/home`.

I just did a clean install of Ubuntu 14.04 (but kept my home folder) and noticed a few things. First of all, my mSATA went from having 29 GB full to only 4 GB. 
I had to re-install several applications from the software center and other repositories.

I am thinking about how to keep my SSD from getting full as I install new software (which tend to install in `/opt` or `/usr`). I believe I can use symbolic links, but was curious if that was the best way, or if I can truly mount them on the other drive.

Additionally are there ways to make some programs install in `/home`? When I download scripts I have placed them in a `~/Apps` folder. The nice thing about this was these programs were preserved after the clean re-install, so I could get back to work faster.

Comment: Check out http://askubuntu.com/questions/656/how-to-move-usr-to-a-new-partition.

Comment: "Additionally are there ways to make some programs install in /home?" If you want to go this way I would suggest ditching Ubuntu and use a system that forces you to compile software yourself so you can tell i where to install. (gentoo or arch(?)). Putting /usr onto a partition would be the wiser choice. /opt is NEVER used with a normal install and should be empty. So this is also easily mounted elsewhere.

Comment: If you want to save some more space AND lower the writes to that disk look voor directories with "./run" (see `/var/run` for instance). Those are locations where files get written more often than elsewhere.