# Managing space between smaller system drive and a larger extension drive

Tags: apt, software-installation, files, disk-usage

I have two drives, one with 150 GB and another with 1 TB. I need to use the 1 TB drive more, since I am running into space issues. By default, all installations (when I do `apt-get`) in my Ubuntu 14.04 system happen in the smaller drive. I have moved some directories to the bigger drive to save space.

How do I manage the filesystem so I use the larger drive for some space-intensive stuff, while I keep the OS and other system related stuff in the smaller drive?

Answer (score 1):

### Move `/home`, `/var` and/or `/usr` folder to external drive

To free up some space, you can move your `/home`, `/var` and/or `/usr` folder to your 1TB drive:

1. Boot into an Ubuntu live CD/USB
2. Shrink the other partitions on the 1TB disk to make space for the new partitions
3. Make new partitions for `/home`, `/var` and/or `/usr`, depending on your preference. They should be of type `ext4`
4. Mount your `root` partition on the 150GB drive and the new partitions you have created somewhere
5. Copy over the files from your root partition with `rsync -avz SOURCE DESTINATION`, e.g. `rsync -avz /mnt/root/usr/ /mnt/usr`, and so on
6. Update `/etc/fstab` to include the new partitions. For example:

   ```
   UUID=b6cf2a0d-2174-4c88-98fc-5502c5630498 /usr ext4 defaults 0 2
   ```

   Make sure you change the UUID (`UUID=b6cf2a0d-2174-4c88-98fc-5502c5630498`), mountpoint (`/usr`) and filesystem (`ext4`) depending on your configuration.
7. Reboot back into Ubuntu, and ensure that your setup works.
8. If all is fine, delete the old files on your 150GB partition:

   ```
   sudo mount --bind / /mnt
   sudo rm -rf /mnt/usr
   sudo umount /mnt
   ```

   where `/usr` is the name of the folder you moved to a separate partition.

Comment: But this will not install new apps into 1TB disks since `apt-get` installs apps in `/usr` directory and not in `/home`. Thus I suggest 1TB should be partitioned into two partitions one mounted at `/home` and other at `/usr` and files from previous `home` and `usr` directories should be moved into new `home` and `usr` directories.

Comment: [This](http://askubuntu.com/questions/656/how-to-move-usr-to-a-new-partition) might help

Comment: I suggest you should edit your answer with moving /usr also so that it may become a complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

@hear I use system links to keep my /home/vinny directory’s on the larger drive .

make a folder/directory on the large drive ,say Ubuntu and move your Documents,pictures,Video,Music,ect,ect folders to it ,,then link them back to your home .
this way the data is on the large drive and whenever you add things to /home/you/Documents it's actually stored on the large drive .

or mount /home/you on the large drive .