# Can't delete old /usr files (moving /usr to new partition)

Tags: partitioning

I'm following [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/668/239261) to move my /usr directory to a different partition. When I try to delete the old /usr files using `sudo rm -r /mnt/usr` or `sudo rm -rf /mnt/usr` I get `rm: cannot remove ‘/mnt/usr’: Device or resource busy`. How do I resolve this?

I have an Ubuntu Live USB so I could try that, but I'm not sure how to delete the old `/usr` files from the live USB either.

---

## Edit:

Here is `/etc/fstab`:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
UUID=ac528df3-12fc-4583-acda-4bb3fbb47fb8 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
UUID=a13080c5-6dde-468d-b5a3-a60d78fe6db0 none            swap    sw              0       0
UUID=0f226bb1-8acb-4343-9db9-b3e27bcea2f1 /home ext4    defaults    0   2
UUID=e21ed5be-d896-4b03-979d-5102b3b039fc /usr               ext3    errors=remount-ro 0       1

/dev/sda1   /media/shirley/windows7 ntfs    uid=1000,gid=1000   0 0
```

My fstab entry for /usr is slightly different from the linked post (e.g. using ext3, and the options are different) because I was initially following this [ubuntuforums post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1048874&s=5fa6c07b52b07b3b2373857cdb097bc3&p=6607399#post6607399) but the overall procedure is the same.

From `sudo lsof | grep /mnt/usr` I just get

```
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
  Output information may be incomplete.
```

... whether I'm mounted on /mnt or not.

## Edit 2:

Here is `/etc/mtab` (after running `sudo mount --bind / /mnt`, which appends the last line):

```
/dev/sdb1 / ext4 rw,errors=remount-ro 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,nodev,noexec,nosuid 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,nodev,noexec,nosuid 0 0
none /sys/fs/cgroup tmpfs rw,uid=0,gid=0,mode=0755,size=1024 0 0
none /sys/fs/fuse/connections fusectl rw 0 0
none /sys/kernel/debug debugfs rw 0 0
none /sys/kernel/security securityfs rw 0 0
udev /dev devtmpfs rw,mode=0755 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620 0 0
tmpfs /run tmpfs rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755 0 0
none /run/lock tmpfs rw,nodev,noexec,nosuid,size=5242880 0 0
none /run/shm tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev 0 0
none /run/user tmpfs rw,nodev,noexec,nosuid,size=104857600,mode=0755 0 0
none /sys/fs/pstore pstore rw 0 0
/dev/sda1 /media/shirley/windows7 fuseblk rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096 0 0
/dev/sda3 /usr ext3 rw,errors=remount-ro 0 0
/dev/sda2 /home ext4 rw 0 0
binfmt_misc /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc binfmt_misc rw,nodev,noexec,nosuid 0 0
systemd /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd cgroup rw,nosuid,noexec,nodev,none,name=systemd 0 0
vmware-vmblock /run/vmblock-fuse fuse.vmware-vmblock rw,nosuid,nodev,default_permissions,allow_other 0 0
gvfsd-fuse /run/user/1000/gvfs fuse.gvfsd-fuse rw,nosuid,nodev,user=shirley 0 0
/ /mnt none rw,bind 0 0
```

Thanks again!

Comment: did you edit /etc/fstab and reboot as suggested in the post?

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `cat /etc/fstab` and the output of `sudo lsof | grep /mnt/usr`

Comment: And please the output of `cat /etc/mtab`

Comment: Thanks for the edit. But you should give me a comment with @A.B. without that, it's very hard for me to notice the edit.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the [mentioned answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/668/239261) twice, there is written you should use the following commands

> $ sudo mount --bind / /mnt
>      $ sudo rm -rf /mnt/usr
>      $ sudo umount /mnt

Therefore use

```
sudo rm -rf /mnt/usr
```

and not

```
sudo rm -r /mnt/usr
```

as you wrote in your question.

and you should read [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/649244/367165) **;)**

---

*My previous answer, maybe helpful for other readers:*

You have mounted a partition at the mount point `/mnt/usr`. With the command `sudo -rf /mnt/usr` you try to delete this mount point and that's not possible. To delete the content of the folder use

```
sudo find /mnt/usr -delete
```

---

More about `find` with

```
man find
```

Comment: Hmm, using `sudo find /mnt/usr -delete` I'm still getting the same "device or resource busy" error

Comment: @sailorbio updated my answer.

Comment: I guess I should have mentioned this earlier but I tried both and they both give me the same error message

Answer (score -1):

run command :

```
fuser -vm /mnt/usr
```

or

```
lsof /mnt/usr
```

run this command as root and see which process and user using `/mnt/usr` and kill that process then try to delete `/mnt/usr` using command.

```
sudo rm -r /mnt/usr
```

you will be able to delete `/mnt/usr`