# Small hard drive, best way to use SD card?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, sd-card

I've installed Linux on my Toshiba Chromebook 2. So far it's awesome and so much more useful than Chrome OS, but it has a tiny SSD size of 16gb. It has an SD card reader and I have a 32gb SD card I'm not using, is there any way I could use it as a hard drive expansion? Or maybe just move my default downloads or applications folder or something on it? I'm new to Ubuntu so maybe this is a dumb question. Any advice would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use manual partitioning during installation?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation) – That would be the easiest way if you're willing to re-install Ubuntu. If you don't want that, please state so in you question and ping me for an alternate suggestion.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of [How to use manual partitioning during installation?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation). Ubuntu is installed in a completely different manner on Chromebooks, this question refers to after install operations.

Answer (score 0):

You can mount your SD card or one partition of it at `/usr`, better do this during Ubuntu installation though. If you have already installed your Ubuntu, try this: [How to move /usr to a new partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/656/how-to-move-usr-to-a-new-partition)

You can also do the same to `/home`, if you tend to have a lot of user files including downloaded stuffs.