# How to install server on /dev/sdb1 on ubuntu

Tags: server, bitcoin

On my ubuntu server, i have /dev/sda that has a single partition of /dev/sda1(30GB) and /dev/sdb that has a single partition of /dev/sdb1 (735GB). i installed bitcoin core on sda1 (default) and it started complaining of space today cos it regularly downloads the block chain. How do i install it on /dev/sdb1 since it is larger. I have to run these commands to install bitcoind

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:bitcoin/bitcoin
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bitcoind
```

Comment: There is no easy way to do this, you can try moving part of your system to the alternate drive. https://askubuntu.com/questions/656/how-to-move-usr-to-a-new-partition

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to move the entire system to the second disk, nor create LVM (which would probably require full system reinstall), I suggest, you examine the bitcoin packages and see where they install or keep data. Then you can copy/move the corresponding directory to a partition on a second disk and mount it with `fstab`.

Comment: if i should try moving everything including ubuntu installation from the /dev/sda1 to the/dev/sdb1, would there be data loss? and how can i set up /dev/sdb1 to be the home boot device? i am connected remotely to the server, i do not have physical access

Comment: If you have no physical access, then the operation is too risky. However, still check where does the bitcoin need the large storage. If this is not any important system direcotry (e.g. `/usr`, `/var`) but some less crucial (like `/opt` or `/usr/local`), you can still move it to another  partition and mount or bind-mount it to its original location.

Answer (score 0):

OR you can create a new folder on second partition/HDD then create a link:

```
ln -s /path/to/newfolder/  ~/.bitcoin/blockchain folder
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to expand my sda1 partition to as much as 1TB. i went to my VM, stopped it, went to the disks menu, edited the disk size, saved it and restarted the VM.