# How to change the disk for the dir that is on home/usr

Tags: disk-management

[image: Home stays and keeps saving in the C disk or main partition while the rest of the files save on the D or second partition]

How do i change the disk the file or directory is being saved to ? Here is this case home would be always saved to the main partition and the other to the second one. The screenshot dosent  have the desktop dir in it but it would be included in the 1. partition.

Thank you.

Comment: That's dependent on the application you are using. For example, if your app is IBM CUA-compliant https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Common_User_Access#Description , you would tap the Alt key then File | save As | and specify where you want the file to go. In this GNOME file manager (AKA Nautilus), click on the Home folder then select the Desktop folder ro save to the Desktop. Which app are you using? Please specify that in the question by clicking on [edit] and then enhance the question for greater clarity.

Comment: Your question is unclear, is it [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/656/how-to-move-usr-to-a-new-partition) what you want to do?

Comment: There is no C and D drives in Ubuntu. In Ubuntu you can have different partitions that can be mounted as any folder in the root file system `/`. The **Home** in the left panel of Files app is actually located in `/home/$USER`. The Other folders such as Documents are located at `/home/$USER/Documents`. When you say "home would be always saved in the main partition. do you mean `/home` or `/home/$USER`? Where is "Home" saved now? Please edit your question and provide new information in the question.

Comment: You can move all of /home, or you can create a data partition and link folders in the data partition back into /home. See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk